# ArrayList won't Add more than one Item

Tags: java

My Array will not add anything to the list after the first and keeps returning null when i search for anything after.

Is there something wrong with this method?

```
public void addItem(Item newItem) throws DuplicateItemException {
    Item tempItem;

    if(itemList == null) 
        itemList.add(newItem);

    try {
        tempItem = findItem(newItem.ID);

        if(tempItem == null) {
            itemList.add(newItem);
        }
        else {
            throw new DuplicateItemException(newItem.ID + "already exists");
        }
    } 
    catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
        itemList.add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. We must be able to copy and paste it in our IDE, and run it. Note that the very first instruction of the method doesn't make sense: it the list is null, you can't possibly add something into it.

Comment: what makes you believe there will be an ItemNotFoundException thrown?

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
if(itemList == null) 
    itemList.add(newItem);
```

if `itemList` is indeed `null`, how can you add to it?

Use this instead

```
if(itemList == null) {
    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.add(newItem);
}
```